# Can we display text to symbols on Primeng?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, primeng

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-menu-demo-twqxb6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) of what  I am trying to do.
I used p-menu from primeng. Is there any way to display text to a symbol like &trade to ™ 3&#8482 to ®?

Comment: Are specifically referring to [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm doing the same, but it needs to be taken. It's taking in angular material components but not taking in primeng

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya Why not just copy paste the special character in the text, it works the same!

Comment: Copy-paste is not possible because this JSON comes from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the `unicode` values, they seem to get rendered without any fancy method.

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem, MessageService, PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [MessageService],
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: MenuItem[];
  apps = [
    { abbreviation: 'app1', full_title: 'Application 1' },
    { abbreviation: 'app2', full_title: 'Application 2 \u2122 ' },
    { abbrebiation: 'app3', full_title: 'Application 3 \u00AE' },
    // Add more items as needed
  ];
  menuItems: { label: SafeHtml; icon: string; command: () => void }[] = [];

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.menuItems = this.apps.map((app) => ({
      label: app.full_title, //this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(app.full_title),
      icon: 'pi pi-fw',
      command: () => this.handleAction(app.abbreviation),
    }));
  }

  handleAction(action: string): void {
    // Handle the selected action
    console.log('Selected Action:', action);
  }
}
```

html

```
<button
  type="button"
  pButton
  pRipple
  icon="pi pi-bars"
  label="Show"
  (click)="menu.toggle($event)"
></button>
<p-menu #menu [popup]="true" [model]="menuItems">
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    <span (click)="handleAction(item.label)">{{ item.label }}</span>
  </ng-template>
</p-menu>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-menu-demo-pu4fbo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts)